# How do I download Android source code and connect it in Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-source, eclipse-adt

I want to see the Android source code, but I don't know how to download it. I only find the address on Stack Overflow.

So my questions are:

1. How do I download the source code from the site https://android.googlesource.com/?
2. How do I install the source code in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Git to download single projects, or you can get the whole tree by following the instructions posted here: https://source.android.com/source/downloading

If you have the full tree you can use the IDE support files located in `development/ide/eclipse`.

Warning: The full tree is **big**. Be sure you have plenty of time and available bandwidth quota, if applicable.

Comment: at last i found,i should use the repo to download all the source code,not the Git,Git just only can download one of the project.thanks.